# IDENTITY column duplication when using BY DEFAULT parameter for Azure Delta tables

Tags: azure-databricks, identity, delta-lake

**Duplicate records are ingested into Azure delta tables when using BY DEFAULT parameter.**

I have followed below steps.

1)Created table with identity column GENERATED BY DEFAULT
2)Inserted 2 records with id, 1 and 2
3)When inserted third row without id, it inserted id as 1 creating duplicates
A similar issue has been reported [here](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009DD70wSAD/identity-column-duplication-when-using-by-default-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

An alter command will solve this.Use below command to sync identity column

**`alter table table_name change column col_name sync identity`**